# I Can't Update table with ormlite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, updates, ormlite

The problem is that I have a table product and my update script doesn't work aparently. It allwas return false.

**Product.class**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Product")
public class Product  {
@DatabaseField(index = true, generatedId = true)
private int productId;

@DatabaseField
private String name;

@DatabaseField
private int quantity;

//@DatabaseField(canBeNull = true)
//private Integer categorie;
//http://logic-explained.blogspot.com.ar/2011/12/using-ormlite-in-android-projects.html

@DatabaseField
private int categorie;

//@ForeignCollectionField
//private ForeignCollection<Categorie> itemsCategorie;  

@DatabaseField
private String description;

@DatabaseField
private String photo;

Product() {
}
public Product(int productId, String name, int quantity,            int categorie, String description, String photo) {
    super();
    this.productId = productId;
    this.name = name;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.categorie = categorie;
    this.description = description;
    this.photo = photo;
}



public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return description;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.description = address;
}
public int getProductId() {
    return productId;
}

public void setProductId(int productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public int getCategorie() {
    return categorie;
}

public void setCategorie(int categorie) {
    this.categorie = categorie;
}

public String getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public void setPhoto(String photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}
public CharSequence getDesc() {
    return null;
}


}
```

**my script updateProduct**

```
public boolean updateProduct(Product p) {
    boolean ret = false;
    if (productDao != null) {
        try {
            productDao = getDao(Product.class);

            UpdateBuilder<Product, Integer> updateBuilder = productDao
                    .updateBuilder();
            updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("name", p.getName());
            updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("quantity", p.getQuantity());
            updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("categorie", p.getCategorie());
            updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("description", p.getDesc());
            updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("photo", p.getPhoto());

            // but only update the rows where the description is some value
            updateBuilder.where().eq("productId", p.getProductId());
            // actually perform the update

            String str = updateBuilder.prepareStatementString();
            // UPDATE `Product` SET `name` = 'gcd' ,`quantity` = 1
            // ,`categorie` = 1 ,`description` = ? ,`photo` = '' WHERE
            // `productId` = 0

            if (productDao.update(updateBuilder.prepare()) != 1) {
                ret = false;
            } else {
                productDao.refresh(p);
                ret = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ret = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

**then I call it with a function like this, but allways return false :(**

```
public boolean updateProduct(Product p) {
    boolean ret = false; 
    try {
        ret = getHelper().updateProduct(p);




    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ret =false;
    }
    return ret;

}
```

I can create and delete but I can not update . I tried everything.
If you please take a moment to answer my question I will appreciate.

Comment: Why don't you use the method `update(Product)` of the DAO ?

Comment: 1) Is there an exception raised (see the log)? If yes, show the stack trace. 2) Does update return 1 ? 3) Is the dao non null ?

Comment: You _certainly_ should be using dao.update(p).  What version of ormlite are you using?  Version 4.39 had some fixed to returning the number of changed rows under Android.  Any chance the object was not created in the database _before_ you updated?  Have you tried dao.createOrUpdate(p)?

Comment: @yDelouis
1. there is not exception
2. the return value is 0
3. dao is not null 
:(

Comment: @Gray the version is 4.42 . The only thing I do is load and edit the record in the database .  And if I using dao.createOrUpdate function always generate a new record in the database. that is weird

Comment: I did it, the thing was that I didn't get the correct id of the object that I wanted to edit. Thanks to all of us for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was 
Simply get the Instance of the object Product from the DB then modify to finaly send to the updateProduct method.

for example first I need to create any method first to get an objet by ID

```
   // get the Instance calling to the  getProductByID
   Product p = getHelper().getProductByID(p.getId())

   //modify any value of the product
   p.setFirstName("asd");

   //call the update
   ret = getHelper().updateProduct(p);
```

then my objects is Updated.

Answer (score 1):

for other developers, if you come face to face with a problem like this you should ensure the table must have an identity key.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "User")
public class User  {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    public int id;
    @DatabaseField
    public String ServiceUserId;
    @DatabaseField
    public boolean IsActive;
    @DatabaseField
    public String FirstName;
    @DatabaseField
    public String LastName;
    @DatabaseField
    public String Key;
    @DatabaseField
    public String Email;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put attention for the object Id(should be the same) and use the natif function update(Product);

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you must override equals and hashCode.